# Need to create a quick poll webpart using the ootb sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to create a quick poll webpart using the out of the box features of SharePoint 2013.

Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a survey app to be able to perform a poll like the one your suggest.

[image]

Assuming you have the following requirements on the poll...

> ## REQUIREMENT
>
> Lets assume you have the following requirements for your feedback collection project.
>
> - Send out a company-wide survey to collect feedback on several topics
> - Respondents can only see their own response
> - Survey administrator can see and export all the responses
> - Entire company should be able to respond to the survey
> - Allow only one response per employee
> - Ability get a report of survey responses

... then just follow the guide ["How to quickly build a Survey using SharePoint 2013"](http://www.siteactions.net/2012/11/08/how-to-quickly-build-a-survey-using-sharepoint-2013/).

Comment: benny need more help on this...I need to add more questions to the survey. since i already answered one question, i am not able to answer the new question.. as it allows to answer only once...i also need to show  a pie chart depending on the user responses to all the users. help....