# How to create Custom Survey app in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, survey, survey-list

I need to create a Custom Survey app part without using the OOTB template, I searched lot but I din't find anything please suggest any links or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use OOTB template, you have to think custom design solution for Survey. Create a custom lists as part of your Information Architecture. Create Pages for admin to create survey. Create a App Part which will display survey questions/poll and a chart to display results..etc..
Please note that this is your custom requirement and you might not find any direct link or tutorial to follow. You have to use your SharePoint skills to design a solution around your requirement. There are some already APP available which you can use directly or can use it as reference.

http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5792

http://www.siteactions.net/2012/11/08/how-to-quickly-build-a-survey-using-sharepoint-2013/

[Need to create a quick poll webpart using the ootb sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70871/need-to-create-a-quick-poll-webpart-using-the-ootb-sharepoint-2013)

http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-survey-web-part/overview/

Hope this helps!!!