# Custom list form insert issue in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to insert custom list in SharePoint Designer, Nothing is happening. I'm trying to do this below requirement.

[Adding survey list in page layout page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/246181/sharepoint-2013-display-survey-question-on-home-page-or-webpart#246203)

Please provide any help.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the Survey list through “Custom List Form” selection.
[image]
[image]

Besides, if you want to create a web part for new form in Survey list, I recommend you creating a aspx file->edit this aspx file in advanced mode-> insert the survey list new form as above->click “To Site Gallery”.

[image]
[image]

Finally, we can add the web part in the publishing page.

[image]